# array passed to nodejs server in url becomes sting

Tags: node.js

My React native front end needs to send an array as params in GET url to nodejs 0.17.x backend server. Here is the code in front end:

```
let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/api/fortrades/bid4post?post_trade_id=${item.id}&bids=${_bids}`; //_bids is an array of integer [37]
let _res = await helper.getAPIp(url, _result, _params, "GET");  //fetch
```

Here is the code on backend server:

```
let bids = req.query.bids && req.query.bids !== [] ? req.query.bids : [];
console.log("bids in bid4post : ", `${bids} ${typeof(bids)} ${bids.length}`);
```

Here is the console outout which shows `bids` as `string`:

```
 bids in bid4post :  37 string 2. //bids should be [37]. Here it is a string 37
```

What is missing here? Do I need to do `bids.json()` to get the original array back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying changin' the parameter name from `bids` to **`bids[]`**

```
let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/api/fortrades/bid4post?post_trade_id=${item.id}&bids[]=${_bids}`;
```